# Empty List of specific type in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I need to create an empty list of specific type. 
I am creating a stack which in internally a list. To create empty stack I need to pass empty list. But how can I pass a empty list of specific type.

```
data Stack' a = Stack' [a] deriving (Show)
main = print("MyName", " ", Stack' Int [])
```

Instead of `Int []`, I have tried `[]::Int` and various other combination with brackets. But no success. Currently I have settled with

```
ls :: [Int]
ls = []
Stack' ls
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Specifying an explicit type

You can set the type after double colons (`::`), like:

```
main = print ("MyName", " ", Stack' [] :: Stack' Int)
```

here we thus set that the type of the third parameter of the 3-tuple is an object with type `Stack' Int`.

or here you can also set the type at the list level (but these are equivalent):

```
main = print ("MyName", " ", Stack' ([] :: [Int]))
```

or more canonical:

```
main = print ("MyName", " ", Stack' ([] :: [] Int))
```

Here we thus specify "*An empty list of type `[Int]`*".

Note that this will print a the value *with* the parenthesis and commas of the 3-tuple:

```
Prelude> print ("MyName", " ", Stack' [] :: Stack' Int)
("MyName"," ",Stack' [])
```

If you want to print this without the "3-tuple noise", you should construct a string, for example by using [**`show :: Show a => a -> String`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:show):

```
main = putStrLn ("MyName " ++ show (Stack' [] :: Stack' Int))
```

This then yields:

```
Prelude> putStrLn ("MyName " ++ show (Stack' [] :: Stack' Int))
MyName Stack' []
```

## Type applications

We can also make use of a *GHC extension*: [**`TypeApplication`**](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-TypeApplications).

In that case we need to compile with the `-XTypeApplication` flag, or write `{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplication #-}` in the head of the file.

We can then specify the type of the type parameter `a` with the `@Type` notation, like:

```
main = print ("MyName", " ", Stack' @Int [])
```

Comment: There's also the type-application option `Stack' ([] @Int)`.

Comment: Ooh, that's better anyway. I didn't think to apply `Stack'` itself to `@Int`.